# Lorentz transformations and rest frame

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems

So a Lorentz transformation leaves the internal product invariant in the Minkowski spacetime. Let's say I do a Lorentz transformation, either a boost or a spatial rotation and I choose the reference frame at rest with this new observer. If I want to describe the metric in these new coordinates ($x'^{\mu}$) the metric is not the simple Minkowski metric anymore, right? I have that

$$\eta'= J^{T} \eta J$$
where $J$ is the Jacobian of the transformation (in this case is just the boost/rotation matrix $\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu}$).

How can I see that it is indeed the same spacetime?

Is there any difference between the above metric and the metric I would obtain with the same procedure but using a more general transformation that leads me to a non-inertial reference frame?

(Maybe in this case the metric is not diagonal anymore?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Lambda$ be any Lorentz transformation and define $x^{\prime}=\Lambda x$ for some coordinates $x$. Then by definition of the Lorentz transformation, the Minkowski inner product is left invariant by this transformation:
$$
x^{\prime T}\eta x^\prime=x^T\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda x=x^T\eta x.
$$
Since this must hold for any $x$, it follows that
$$
\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda=\eta.
$$
In fact, this is really the *definition* of the Lorentz group.

In any case, observe that the Jacobian of the Lorentz transformation $x^\prime=\Lambda x$ is
$$
J=\Lambda.
$$
using this, your question of invariance of the metric follows immediately from the definition of the Lorentz transformations.

Comment: I see, it makes sense. But if it's not a Lorentz transformation then the metric clearly changes. 

The question came from me calculating the metric in spherical coordinates. 
What is the observer to whom spherical coordinates are adapted? Is it non-inertial? Because the metric is different from Minkowski

Comment: @Phrancesco A metric is an object defined intrinsically upon a manifold. Changing coordinates does not change the metric, only the metric components. If you want to work with other coordinate systems, you would be better off working with this machinery (essentially GR techniques applied to Minkowski). In that language, we would define Lorentz transformations as those generated by vector fields which are Killing vectors of the Minkowski metric. This is now a coordinate-independent description.

Comment: @Phrancesco Let me also add that if you would like to work in more general coordinate systems, please perform the following replacement in my descriptions above: $x\rightarrow dx$ and the same for the primes. To be more correct, which is necessary in other coordinates, we need to be computing the invariant length $ds^2=\eta_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu\otimes dx^\nu$.

Comment: Taking the definition of Lorentz transformations as those which leave the Minkowski metric unchanged, I want to ask that the line element (proper time) is unchanged under any arbitrary coordinate transformation. That is not only the Lorentz transformation but any transformation will leave the metric unchanged. So why do we define Lorentz transformation as those which leave the interval unchanged when the fact is that any arbitrary transformation leaves the interval unchnaged

Comment: @Shashaank The coordinate independent statement would be that Lorentz transformations are those diffeomorphisms generated by vector fields which are Killing vectors of the Minkowski metric. While $g=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ is indeed coordinate invariant, that is not the same as being invariant under a given diffeomorphism. However, I believe that's outside the scope of OP's original question and should be made a question of its own (though I would think such a question has likely been asked before).

Comment: @RichardMyers ok thanks. Could you please suggest any book or lecture notes at a level lower than Wald ( except Caroll) for the mathematics

Comment: @Shashaank Carroll would be my go-to reference. There used to be a very nice online text by Stephen C. Preston on differential geometry if you can find it.